# Kotlin: NoSuchMethod when invoking from java

Tags: kotlin

I packaged a kotlin project and when I use it on other kotlin projects it work as expected. However using from a Java project I'm getting an exception on the class constructor:

Here's the SensorData.kt file

```
package io.igx.iot.model

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.util.*


/**
 * @author Vinicius Carvalho
 */
data class SensorData(val type: String, val name: String, @JsonProperty("@timestamp") val timestamp: Date, val value: Double, val thermostatId: String)
data class Column(val type: String, val position: Int)
data class Report(val device: String, val id: String, val start: LocalDate, val end: LocalDate)


inline fun String.safeFloat() : Float {
    return try {
        this.toFloat()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException){
        0.0f
    }
}

inline fun String.safeDouble() : Double {
    return try {
        this.toDouble()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException){
        0.0
    }
}

inline fun String.safeInt() : Int {
    return try {
        this.toInt()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException){
        0
    }
}

inline fun String.safeLong() : Long{
    return try {
        this.toLong()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException){
        0L
    }
}
```

When I run a java app that uses a class that internally uses this data class, I'm getting an exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.igx.iot.model.SensorData.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Date;DLjava/lang/String;)V

Am I missing something from the data class?

Update:

Just to be clear, the SensorData class is never invoked from the java code, instead another kotlin class called EcobeeParser invokes it:

```
sensors.add(SensorData(column.type, entry.key, date, read, report.id))
```

And this class `EcobeeParser` is invoked in the java code as:

`EcoBeeParser parser = new EcoBeeParser(new FileInputStream(new File("")), 19);`

That's what fails, however in a kotlin project this works:

`val parser = EcobeeParser(FileInputStream(File)), 19)`

Comment: The error says `(String, String, Date, String)` and the primary constructor says `(String, String, Date, Double, String)`.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, however I don't understand why is the code internally calling the wrong constructor. The same code in kotlin works, just when used via java there's a problem

Comment: You could try giving the bytecode a check.

Comment: Is this pro guarded?